# How to decide when a group of markers should become a cluster?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to cluster markers that are almost near each other but they cluster when I zoom out a exact distance.
So my question is, is there any option to choose when markers should be clustered based on the distance between them?

Here are two image of how it works now in my app:

[Clustered markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNrT6.jpg)

[Unclustered markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Mm1.jpg)

Well so in the unclustered markers image, in the left side there are three markers almost together and they dont cluster, you can't even  see one of them.

Comment: There are few algorithms that can be used for clustering points based on the distance metrics in the square affinity matrix. DBSCAN is one of them if you don't know the number of clusters in advance

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: There's a useful utility that Google Maps provides.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering